# How to build a relational database system with 4 tables in arcgis desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class, database-design, relates

I have been given data from an working online application which consists of a relational model. My aim is to recreate the model using Arcgis Desktop.

I have the table "elements" containing Point geometry with the attribute element_id as the primary key. In the table Aspects, Types and media. The tables "Aspects" and "Media" have a 1:1 relationship with "elements" and media has a 1:m relationship.

It is possible to build these multiple relationships in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to specify whether you are talking about ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS for Server, the ArcGIS Platform as a whole or something more specific, please?  Many-to-many can be handled using relationship classes but can you also include some more background to your question to focus it some more.

Comment: I'd overlooked that you mentioned desktop in your question title so will now edit that into its body and tag.

Comment: What makes this hard, even if you're using MS SQL Server or PostGIS is that creating spatial views or tables that are constructed using SQL joins, relates, etc. are difficult - though not impossible - to consume using ArcMap. Building a table that joins geometry to features by an ID requires not only the geometry, but a unique ID column in order to be displayed. ArcMap cannot index/optimize the data, however, as that is what it uses all the extra tables in ArcSDE for (how quickly a MSSQL/PostGIS database gets clogged up so quickly...) But we're doing this at DPS and its going OK for some tasks

Comment: I think that you should try putting these tables into a file geodatabase and then to create relationship classes for each relationship you describe.  If that does not "just work" then you should be in a position to ask a more focussed and answer-able question.  I think your question needs to also so what data storage requirements you have i.e. is SQL Server in the picture (or not), file geodatabase OK (or not), etc

Comment: what did i miss ? why not use FGDB with few relationship class to these tables including many-to-many ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have [related tables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002t000000) in ArcGIS Desktop, but it sounds like what you're really trying to do might be adding [Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Attachments_toolset/00170000015m000000/). There are pros and cons to both approaches, particularly if you ever want to work with Server or Online ([related tables coming soon!](http://video.esri.com/watch/3838/arcgis-apps))

Aside from just building the relationships, give careful consideration to how you plan to update and maintain the data.